# Need help with a "Describe all"-type exercise

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to complete an exercise from Artin's Algebra group section:

*Describe all homomorphisms $\varphi : \mathbb{Z}^+ \to \mathbb{Z}^+$. Determine which are injective, which are surjective, and which are isomorphisms. $\mathbb{Z}^+$ is the group of integers with + as law of composition.*

My problem specifically comes from the part "Describe all", I find this too general and it makes me have doubts about where to start and finish the exercise.

- Where should I start? Should I just start enumerating properties from this type of homomorphism?
- How do I know I'm done describing?

In general, what should I do when I'm asked to describe or characterize a certain structure?

Comment: For people to help you better, you should specify the exact definition of $\Bbb Z^+$, and the structure you give it.

Comment: By "describe" people tend to mean something like "characterize with necessary and/or sufficient conditions to identify the thing in question." If $\mathbb Z^+$ denotes the integers under addition, your description will be something along the lines of "if $\varphi$ is injective, then we also know such and such about $\varphi$..."

Comment: Are you allowed to introduce a multiplicative structure on $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @AaronMaroja no, only addition.

Comment: $\phi(1)$ can be any element of ${\mathbb Z}$, and then $\phi(n) = n\phi(1)$, so $\phi$ is completely determined by $\phi(1)$.

Comment: Here is a "describe all" question on homomorphisms (which is repeatedly asked on MSE): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57279/question-about-all-the-homomorphisms-from-mathbbz-to-mathbbz.